# TFS2015 running SoapUI test as unit tests - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, soapui, tfs-2015

I'm trying to run SoapUI tests as unit tests as described here:
http://blog.simplecode.eu/post/Soap-UI-testing-with-MsTest

Everything works nice when I'm running test locally in visual studio.
But when I'm trying to run those tests during the build process on tfs2015 i get "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine":

[image]

My other unit tests during that build are performed correctly.
Anyone had similar issue?

Comment: that is a very generic error, should be able see plenty of result on google and apply the appropriate to resolve. By the way, how it is related to `soapui` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage, to fix that - problem was enabled code coverage. Disabling it fixed to problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a **really build error** in TFS. You can see the result in your screenshot, build **partially succeeded**.

Currently, by default the build result is "**Failed**" if anything failed to **compile**, "**Partially Succeeded**" if there are any unit test failures, and "Succeeded" otherwise.

Build is reported as "Partially Succeeded" when the "Test Success" property is set to "False" and "CompilationSuccess"="True"

So your error is more like something in your code fails the test or some configuration related to test in the build definition or build agent environment. Since everything works nice when you are running test locally in visual studio.

Seems disable  code coverage fixed the issue.